# How to if machine is a windows PC using IP Address or Hostname?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, ip, host

I have an IP Address and hostname/computer name of machines in the network.

The machines could either be linux PCs, windows PCs, Mac Computers, or printers.

I want to filter out which one's are the windows PCs and i am trying to find a command for that.

The closest i got was using

```
systeminfo /s \\computer_name
```

This returns unreachable on a non windows PC, so that is good. But if the PC is windows, it requires that the current user has admin privileges on the remote PC, otherwise it also returns unreachable. I dont want the user to input any credentials, so all i have as input is just the IP address and hostname.

What other way or command can be used? It can be any command/way. My objective is just to determine if it is a windows machine or not. It could be using batch files or java code. I will be using java, so I can call a batch file but if there is a java specific way it would be good too.

Or any other way to implement windows pc discovery using java?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer https://superuser.com/questions/323238/how-can-i-determine-the-os-of-a-remote-computer which suggests using either systeminfo or wmic